# RobotFramework - Execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, robotframework, executor

I'm trying to inject my browser with JavaScript Executor function to get back into running instance of a browser. For it, I'm using the keyword "Exectute JavaScript" My code looks like this:

```
SeleniumLibrary.Execute Javascript           JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("alert('OK')")
```

Error looks like this:

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
```

(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)

It looks like import for JavaScriptExecutor? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
SeleniumLibrary.Execute Javascript   alert('OK')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the alert shows but my code doesn't continue and it doesn't click on the elements after, should I somehow handle the alert first?

Comment: Ok I handled with the keyword "Handle Alert" but this still doesn't get me back to the running instance of a browser :(.

Answer (score 0):

The alert should be handled with the `Handle Alert` keyword as you seem to have done already. For returning to earlier browser instance Selenium provides two entities which can be used. You may want to see the [Browsers and Windows](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Browser%20and%20Window) section of the SeleniumLibrary documentation.

Basic use case is that when opening browser, you'll give it an *alias* and then use `Switch Browser` to get back to that browser instance. Within that browser you may have multiple pages open, they can be accessed with normal locators by using `Switch Window` [keyword](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Switch%20Window). For example I would commonly use the window URL as that tends to have at least some unique part in it. If none of the URL, title, or name are unique, by using keyword `Get Window Handles` returns a list of windows within that browser. In your case, expecting no other windows are opened during the test, the main browser window can be found with argument `MAIN`.

You may consider this incomplete example and fill in your specifics which you did not provide in the question.

```
Test 1
    Open Browser    ${your URL}    alias=browser1
    # Do whatever triggers the alert
    Handle Alert
    Switch Window    MAIN
```